# Work with <video> and <track>

Tags: javascript, html5-video

How to work with `<track>` in video? I want to get word from track text when mouse on this word.

```js
var track = document.getElementById('ger').track;
var cues = track.cues;
var active_cues = track.activeCues;
var text = active_cues[0].text;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Video/video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
   <track id="ger" kind="subtitles" src="Video/Twitter_in_Plain_English_ger.vtt" srclang="de">
</video>
```

Comment: You've told us what you want to do, but you haven't told us what part you're having trouble with. Please be specific.

Comment: i need get word from subtitle text when mouse on word, but i dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation for tracks I think what you want would look something like this:

```
var videoElement = document.querySelector("video");//get video element where you want tracks
var track = videoElement.textTracks[0]; //get first track element that contains cues
var activeCue = track.activeCues[0]; //get first active cue
var cueText = activeCue.text; // get the text of active cue
console.log(cueText); display text in dev console
```

Also, here is a nice full tutorial on using tracks: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/